# Any API available for LiquiBase

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase

There is a requirement about a user interface to provide options to upgrade database change if there is new service pack for current Spring web application(with OpenJPA).

Seems LiquiBase is a good option. But I haven't found any articles or document about LiquiBase API that can detect new schema change(either from database or change log). It looks like LiquiBase is more a "silence upgrade" option on development level, so each time developer can create new change log and let Maven to auto upgrade database schema.

But is there any option we can provide front end user to click a button to upgrade the schema by their choice, then show user error when it fails and roll back? In general is there some Java API can wrap with Spring framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Liquibase is just a Java library. Its API is described here: http://www.liquibase.org/api/index.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. Yes the JavaDoc is helpful, but drag me into quite a learning curve. Is there any article or doc that I can read and do Some customized implementation? i.e. I want to design a Java function that auto detect an update in the ChangeLog. How can we achieve that? Where can I find information for this kind of stuff?

Comment: The Liquibase API javadoc is now [here](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say a really hated Liquibase mainly because I just for some reason could not get it to work.

You might want to give this a try:

http://flywaydb.org/

Otherwise (since it sounds like your shipping a product) you can create two installs: one of the old version and one of the new version.

Do a schema dump for each install and then diff them. Create an up and down sql script based on the diffs.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It seems flyway requires additional storage for multiple version, which currently is now feasible in my situation. I get LiquiBase working but it is pretty smooth.

Comment: But also I have to mention that both `Flyway` and `Liquibase` doesn't update its document timely. Either lack of API doc or not quite catch up with latest version. But as utilities developed by small group, that's pretty reasonable. So it is not a complain, but hope later we can have more doc to use to reduce learning curve.

Comment: @Subarule I have given up on almost all the Schema Evolution tools. They always seem harder than just some up (add schema) and down (rollback schema) sql scripts that I can create on my own by just diffing the schemas.